# Bad file descriptor (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I can't launch Spyder after updating to the version 4.2.1. the issue is:

```
spyder return
Bad file descriptor (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
```

Comment: I made sure that the installed versions of PyQTWebEngine and PyQT5 complied with the requirements of Spyder

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? If so are you sure that you have permissions to write in the places Sypder need?

Comment: Hi  talonmies, spyder does run on the win 10 , but I make sure it has sufficient permissions to run. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Stopped Working on Jupyter StartUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690540/python-stopped-working-on-jupyter-startup)

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution offered here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/93997763402/

Effectively

1. Uninstall Pyzmq, Pip Uninstall Pyzmq under Anaconda Prompt
2. Install the old version, Conda Install Pyzmq==19.0.2

Comment: Seems to affect Jupyter notebook running, too. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/unable-to-run-jupyter-notebook-after-update-localhost/10764/8?u=fomightez) for a post on the Jupyter Discourse where a similar error occurred and downgrading pyzmq worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper solution.

I guess you're using a VPN or proxy server.

If then, resetting winsocket will solve that problem.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4177#issuecomment-508160557

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is Changing the Kernel in Vsocde followed by `conda install -n <env name> ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall` (If no kernel is found in current ENV)
[image]